# How to setup magento to run cron job where each product has different date when to update

Tags: php, magento, cron

I have cron import script to get products from some url, and when I import this products I set date when each product need to be updated. Is it possible to setup some autocron job for each product while I'm getting it from the url.
Or I should create method which will run every minute and check products are they ready for update?

Comment: I would do the latter, though every minute might be excessive

Comment: yep. I would go with the second approach. You can even make it run at 5 minutes (or 10) and check the product availability on an interval instead of a fixed date.

Comment: But what if product have to update every 30s?